# Testing rails-4-autocomplete with send keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I have a customer model with has many association with order model, I'm using 'rails4-autocomplete' gem for customer choice, so I have in order model:

```
belongs_to :customer
delegate :nickname, to: :customer, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

and in my order controller

```
autocomplete :customer, :nickname, full: false
```

in my new order view:

```
<%= f.input :customer_id, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :customer_nickname, as: :autocomplete,
     label: "Client: ", 
     url: autocomplete_customer_nickname_orders_path,
     input_html: { :style => 'height: 35px', 'data-id-element' => '#order_customer_id', autocomplete: 'off' } %>
```

Now I'm testing with rspec and capybara, so I have in gem file:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring', '~> 1.3.5'

  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'ffaker'

  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

In my test I have:

```
    let(:user) {  FactoryGirl.create(:user) }    
    it 'make an order', :js => true do
    c1 = FactoryGirl.create(:customer, nickname: 'aldo')
    c2 = FactoryGirl.create(:customer, nickname: 'giovanni')
    c3 = FactoryGirl.create(:customer, nickname: 'giacomo')
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    visit new_order_path
    expect(page).to_not have_content 'aldo'
    expect(page).to_not have_content 'giovanni'
    expect(page).to_not have_content 'giacomo'


    fill_in "Client", :with => 'gi'
    expect(page).to_not have_content 'aldo'
    expect(page).to have_content 'giovanni'
    expect(page).to have_content 'giacomo'

    element = ***
    element.native.send_keys(:down_arrow, :return)
```

With what I have to fill *** to select first customer? I tried everything but nothing works... Any help? I tried also simple-send-keys gem but it is incompatible with capybara 2.5.0 (I am on Rails 4.2.0)

Edit: my external html is:

```
<input style="height: 35px" data-id-element="#order_customer_id" autocomplete="off" class="autocomplete optional ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete="/orders/autocomplete_customer_nickname" name="order[customer_nickname]" id="order_customer_nickname" type="text">
```

so my unique selector is `#order_customer_nickname` and I tried `element = find('#order_customer_nickname')` but I am getting selenium error:

```
Failure/Error: element.native.send_keys(:down_arrow, :return)
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnsupportedOperationError:
       no such key :down_arrow
```

Edit2: I tried also

```
page.execute_script %Q{ $('#order_customer_nickname').trigger('focus') }
page.execute_script %Q{ $('#order_customer_nickname').trigger('keydown') }
page.execute_script %Q{ $('#order_customer_nickname').trigger('enter') }
```

and this is not getting errors, but still doesn't work...

Comment: Solved! I was mistaking selenium sintax, correct way is: element = find('#order_customer_nickname')
    element.native.send_keys(:arrow_down, :return)

Comment: If you're using a recent Capybara the .native shouldn't be required - just element.send_keys(:arrow_down, :return)  should work

Comment: You are right.. Native is not necessary.. Thanks!